# Uninstall Gitorious

Tags: centos, uninstall, git

I have installed Gitorious on my CentOS server but the ssh public key authentication method does not serve my purpose as most of the users are on Windows and will be using more than one computer. I want to completely remove Gitorios before installing Gitlab on my server. Can anyone tell me how to remove Gitorious completely?

I followed the instructions at http://getgitorious.com/installer to install it. The Uninstall instructions are nowhere to be found.

Comment: if you don'tell how you installed it, then i guess 
yum remove gitorious*

Answer (score 1):

Given that you followed the instructions on the page you linked, you likely ran this script:

http://gitorious.org/gitorious/ce-installer/blobs/master/install

To uninstall it, you can either go through and manually undo what the script's done, or just enough to get it so that it's no longer running and useful. There doesn't seem to be a simple "undo everything" as it's a Rails application that appears to touch many parts of the system.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but it was the answer I needed...